# how can i send mail from my database connected with asp.net website

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am developing an asp.net Website which is connected with SQL database, SQL database has two columns START_DATE and END_DATE, so I want if END_DATE is greater than START_DATE then it send a mail automatically even when the website is not in use..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: You need to learn the basic first.

Comment: This is usually done using some kind of background service or scheduler, not with ASP.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible paths:

1. Create a job in your SQL server to monitor the table and send emails when you want.
2. Create a windows service which queries the table every so often to see if an email needs to be sent.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick Response, i am trying this, I guess it will solve my problem, Thanks alot for ur help..